# HTML disabled property set to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I came across a this snippet in a web page:

```
<input type="image" src="http://www.foo.bar.com/image.gif" disabled="window.open('http://www.foo.com');return false;">
```

yet as state in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_disabled.asp
Shouldn't `disabled` property of a element be a boolean value?

How can I get the `disabled` function as a string, in the above example, I would like to get

```
var str = 'window.open('http://www.foo.com');return false;'
```

Comment: It's just a variable assignment. Poor choice of name. It can also be `var myIntergerNumber = "hello";`. Programmer can choose any name he wants to any variable he/she assigns.

Comment: If you mean you want to execute the command stored in the variable, use `eval()` but keep in mind it's not a good practice.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I update the post, it's inside a `input` element.

Comment: That's indeed very weird on the verge of invalid HTML.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I thought it weird too. But it seems not so rare to see this usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

```
var str = $("#id")[0].getAttribute("disabled")
```

Comment: That works. Interesting... I use `$("#id")[0].disabled` and it just return `true`!

Comment: @AllanRuin JQ will explicitly return a boolean for "disabled" (`return elem.disabled === true`)